# Computation of the 3-dimensional $\mathbb{Z}/m$-equivariant spin cobordism group (with possibly non-empty fixed-point set)?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, cobordism, spin-geometry

$\newcommand{\odd}{\mathrm{odd}}\newcommand{\ev}{\mathrm{ev}}$Consider tuples of the form $(Y,\mathfrak{s},\widehat{\sigma})$ where: $Y$ is a closed oriented 3-manifold, $\mathfrak{s}$ is a spin structure on $Y$, $\sigma:Y\to Y$ is a self-diffeomorphism of order $m\geq 2$, and $\widehat{\sigma}$ is a lift of $\sigma$ to a *spin* diffeomorphism (i.e., a bundle automorphism of the principal $\text{Spin}(3)$-bundle associated to $\mathfrak{s}$. Note that $\sigma$ lifts to a spin diffeomorphism iff $\sigma$ acts trivially on $H^{1}(Y,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Furthermore, spin lifts of diffeomorphisms come in two flavors: call $\widehat{\sigma}$ *even* if $\widehat{\sigma}^{m}=\text{id}$, and call $\widehat{\sigma}$ *odd* if $\widehat{\sigma}^{m}$ is equal to the *spin flip*, i.e., the bundle automorphism given by multiplication by $-1$ in each fiber. In the latter case, $\widehat{\sigma}$ is of order $2m$. We will call this property the *parity* of $\widehat{\sigma}$ (which is unrelated to the parity of $m$).

I am interested in a presentation of the cobordism group $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m}_{3}$, where the equivalence relation is defined as follows: given two tuples $(Y_{1},\mathfrak{s}_{1},\widehat{\sigma}_{1})$ and $(Y_{2},\mathfrak{s}_{2},\widehat{\sigma}_{2})$ as above, we say that $(Y_{1},\mathfrak{s}_{1},\widehat{\sigma}_{1})$ is *$\mathbb{Z}/m$-equivariantly spin cobordant* to $(Y_{2},\mathfrak{s}_{2},\widehat{\sigma}_{2})$ if there exists a tuple $(X,\mathfrak{t},\widehat{\tau})$ with: $(X,\mathfrak{t})$ a compact spin 4-manifold, $\tau:X\to X$ a self-diffeomorphism of order $m$, and $\widehat{\tau}$ a spin lift of $\tau$, such that $\partial X=-Y_{1}\cup Y_{2}$, $\mathfrak{t}|_{Y_{j}}=\mathfrak{s}_{j}$, and $\widehat{\tau}|_{Y_{j}}=\widehat{\sigma}_{j}$ for $j=1,2$.

Note that $(Y_{1},\mathfrak{s}_{1},\widehat{\sigma}_{1})$ and $(Y_{2},\mathfrak{s}_{2},\widehat{\sigma}_{2})$ are equivariantly spin cobordant only if $\widehat{\sigma}_{1}$ and $\widehat{\sigma}_{2}$ have the same parity, in which case the cobordism is realized via $(X,\mathfrak{t},\widehat{\tau})$ with the parity of $\widehat{\tau}$ agreeing with that of $\widehat{\sigma}_{1}$, $\widehat{\sigma}_{2}$. Therefore $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m}_{3}$ splits as a direct sum $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m}_{3}=\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m,\ev}_{3}\oplus\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m,\odd}_{3}$, and so it suffices to consider each component separately.

Here is what I can deduce so far: the variation of the above setting where all of the group actions are free (and we restrict to *even* spin diffeomorphisms) is governed by the cobordism group $\Omega^{\text{Spin}}_{3}(B\mathbb{Z}/m)$. Via the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence $H_{p}(B\mathbb{Z}/m;\Omega^{\text{Spin}}_{q}(*))\Rightarrow\Omega^{\text{Spin}}_{p+q}(B\mathbb{Z}/m)$, one can show that

$$\Omega^{\text{Spin}}_{3}(B\mathbb{Z}/m)\cong{
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{lll}
            \mathbb{Z}/m & \mbox{if } m\text{ is odd.} \\
            \mathbb{Z}/m'\oplus\mathbb{Z}/8 & \mbox{if } m=2m', m'\text{ odd.} \\
            \mathbb{Z}/m'\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2^{k+1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2 & \mbox{if } m=2^{k}m', k\geq 2, m'\text{ odd.}
        \end{array}
    \right.
}$$

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there exists a similar approach to calculate $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m,\ev}_{3}$ or $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m,\odd}_{3}$. One can show that the subgroup of $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m,\ev}_{3}$ generated by $(Y,\mathfrak{s},\widehat{\sigma})$ with $\sigma:Y\to Y$ a free action is a quotient of $\Omega^{\text{Spin}}_{3}(B\mathbb{Z}/m)$, but beyond that I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Since we are working in a low dimension, I am wondering if there is a more "hands-on" way to approach this calculation using equivariant handle calculus or something similar. My intuition tells me that $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m}_{3}$ is non-trivial since this is the case for $\Omega^{\text{Spin}}_{3}(B\mathbb{Z}/m)$, but I could very well be wrong. Moreover, I am particularly interested in the subgroup of $\Omega^{\text{Spin},\mathbb{Z}/m}_{3}$ generated by spin rational homology spheres -- so even if anyone can calculate this particular subgroup, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: You can incorporate the spin flip by looking at the bordism group for the structure group $\frac{\operatorname{Spin}(3) \times \mathbb{Z}/2m}{\mathbb{Z}/2}$ where I modded out the diagonal $\mathbb{Z}/2$. You can also compute this bordism group using a variation of Atiyah-Hirzebruch. So I guess your example can be extended to odd spin diffeomorphisms.